# free() function not freeing heap memory

Tags: c, malloc, free

**I have 3 files proj2.c, duplicate.h, duplicate.c
proj2.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "duplicate.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char **copy = duplicate_args(argc, argv);
    char **p = copy;
    argv++;
    p++;

    while (*argv)
    {
        //printf("%s %s\n", argv[1], copy[1]);
        printf("%s %s\n", *argv++, *p++);
    }

    free_duplicated_args(copy);
    //free(copy);
    return 0;
}
```

**duplicate.h:**

```
char **duplicate_args(int argc, char **argv);

void free_duplicated_args(char **copy);
```

**duplicate.c:**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char **duplicate_args(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char **arrPointer=malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(char*));
        for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
        {
                arrPointer[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[i])*sizeof(char));
                for(int j=0;j<strlen(argv[i]);j++)
                {
                        if(argv[i][j] > 64 && argv[i][j] < 91)
                        {
                                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]+32;
                        }
                        else if(argv[i][j] > 96 && argv[i][j] < 123)
                        {
                                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]-32;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j];
                        }
                }
//              arrPointer[i]=argv[i];

        }
        return arrPointer;
}

void free_duplicated_args(char **copy)
{
        free(copy);
}
```

**Program is fairly simple. Takes n arguments and change the capitalization of strings. I am creating a new array to store copy of argv (using malloc). Now when I run valgrind: valgrind --leak-check=full ./proj2 1
It says 1 byte lost.**

```
==10412== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10412==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==10412==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 1,033 bytes allocated
==10412== 
==10412== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==10412==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==10412==    by 0x10927C: duplicate_args (in /root/Documents/OS/proj2/project/proj2)
==10412==    by 0x109194: main (in /root/Documents/OS/proj2/project/proj2)
==10412== 
==10412== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10412==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==10412==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10412==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10412==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10412==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10412== 
==10412== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10412== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: the duplicate.h file is missing the needed 'include guard'  Similar to: `#ifndef DUPLICATE_H  newline #define DUPLICATE_H ... body of header here....   #endif // DUPLICATE_H

Comment: OT: in function: `main()`, regarding: `if (argc <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }`   This will result in the program suddenly exiting without telling the user what is wrong.  Suggest replacing: `return 1;` with `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <description of expected parameters>\n", argv[0] );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char **arrPointer = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(char*));`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful   If not successful call `perror( "your error message" ); To display on `stderr` your error message and the test reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `arrPointer[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[i])*sizeof(char));`   1) sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1,  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect and just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) as in my prior comment, always check for and handle any errors.  3) The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  \ 4) this fails to allow room for the terminating NUL byte

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(argv[i][j] > 64 && argv[i][j] < 91)
                        {
                                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]+32;  Much better to 1) `#include <ctype.h>`  2) use: `char temp = argv[i][j];  if( isupper( temp ) { arrPointer[i][j] = tolower( temp );   etc.  Similar modifications to the `else if` and `else` statements.   Note: the `else` can be removed and the second `if()` be reduced to `arrPointer [i][j] = toupper( temp );`

Comment: regarding: `void free_duplicated_args(char **copy)
{
        free(copy);
}`   Every call to `malloc()` must be matched by a call to `free()`, preferably in the opposite order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `duplicate_args` calls `malloc` `argc` times, while `free_duplicated_args` calls `free` only once, that's why you have memory leak.  Should be

```
void free_duplicated_args(int argc, char **copy)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        free (copy [i]);

    free(copy);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: It only calls `malloc` `argc` times, not `argc + 1`; the loop is from `1` to `< argc`, or `argc - 1` calls, plus the `malloc` outside the loop. They don't perform a `malloc` for `argv[0]`. They don't adjust indices properly though, so they're not using the first index in their top level array, and they're writing one past the end on the other side. It's a mess.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for pointing that out. I will be fixing that now.